# Javascript click event - find all occurrences

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a javascript that occurs on a click event on a table. The code works as it should, and only slidetoggles the first "p" it finds. I would like the code to slidetoggle all occurrences of "p" up to the next 'name' and 'info'.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("td[colspan=1]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        alert(event.target);
        // var current_event = $(event.currenttarget);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 )
        {
            $target.slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
            // alert(event.currentTarget);
            // var currentEventTarget = event.currentTarget; // this outputs: Object object
            // document.write(event.currentTarget.nodeName); // this outputs: TABLE 
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
        }                    
    });
});
```

And the table looks like this (I borrowed this from somewhere else):

```
<table>
    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="1"><p>Blah 1</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="1"><p>Blah 2</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="1"><p>Blah 3</p></td></tr>
</table>
```

So, when clicking the first row, currently it only toggles the 'Blah1' and clicking row two toggles the 'Blah 3'. I would like clicking the first row to toggle, 'Blah 1' and 'Blah 2'.

I hope that makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Rgds

EDIT: as a side note I need to be able to click the Blahs later on, as they will take me to a separate webpage. I haven't worked out how to do that yet. But not necessary for this particular question.

EDIT2: after searching more, I have found `nextAll()`, maybe that can help? But I don't know how to use it. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$target.closest("tr").nextAll("p").slideToggle();
```

EDIT3: I have solved it by accident. I introduced a class="stop" in the `<tr>`for each row. And used the following code:

```
$target.closest("tr").nextUntil("tr.stop").find("p").slideToggle();
```

This now finds each "p" until the next row creation. So each clicks displays all rows associated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to achieve this would be to give a class name to the < p> tag and toggle them as shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("td[colspan=1]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
       // alert(event.target);
        // var current_event = $(event.currenttarget);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 )
        {
            $target.slideUp();
        }
        else if($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") == 1)
        {
            // alert(event.currentTarget);
            // var currentEventTarget = event.currentTarget; // this outputs: Object object
            // document.write(event.currentTarget.nodeName); // this outputs: TABLE 
           //$target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
       $( ".toggle1" ).slideToggle( "slow" );

        }                    
    });
 $( ".toggle2" ).click(function() {
  $( ".toggle2This" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="1"><p class="toggle1">Blah 1</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="1"><p class="toggle1">Blah 2</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="toggle2"><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="1"><p class="toggle2This">Blah 3</p></td></tr>
</table>
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The only issue with this, is I am going to end up with a LOT of Names, age, infos - not just the two shown. So i need something dynamic so I don't have to add to the code everytime I add a new age. Is there another way round?

Comment: I managed to find this after shed loads of searching, nextAll() - but i don't know how to use it, something like $target.closest("tr").nextAll("p").slideToggle(); but this doesnt work.

Comment: @Surreall why are you adding same Name, Age, Info twice in one table? Can you seperate them and make 2 tables instead? it's not feasible to create same table headers twice in one table.

Comment: I was using those as an example, in reality I was getting values from a mysql query to create the table. And then creating the table in a similar format. But eitherway nextUntil() worked great.